# export and import taxonomy terms from one taxonomy to another

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

- I have a custom taxonomy named *"places"* and another taxonomy named
  *"featured places"*.
- On the *"places" taxonomy* i have 150 terms (names of places) and i
  want those same 150 names (terms) on the *"featured places"
  taxonomy*.

**Is there a way to just export the terms from the *"places" taxonomy* and export it into the *"featured places" taxonomy?***

Thanks!

Comment: Did you create the taxonomies with your own code? If so, just change the label for "places" to "featured places" without changing the ID it is registered with and you'll achieve the desired effect without moving any data around!  And then ditch the new but empty "featured places" taxonomy.

Comment: No problem - I've put my comment into an answer - if it's acceptable then please do accept it to keep the site tidy.

Comment: Did that work for you in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just change the label for the taxonomy "places" to "featured places" without changing the ID it is registered with and you'll achieve the desired effect without moving any data around! And then ditch the new but empty "featured places" taxonomy.